# Connect USB external cd/dvd drive to a BOSE sound system

Tags: usb, audio, compact-disc, bose

I don't know if it's the right forum, but lets go, I have a BOSE radio cd player model CD-3000 from 1999, I would like to ask if is possible to connect a external USB CD/DVD drive (used for laptops/desktops) (I attached the pic.) to this BOSE ? It has RCA inputs to connect another player or something else compatible, I would connect with a cable USB-RCA, will it behave as a regular CD player?? Will it be controlled from BOSE remote control ? I ask this because the BOSE CD player not recognize any CD anymore, the optical laser is out of order and the cost to repair is too expensive. I know, I can buy a cheap regular CD player and connect to BOSE but I would like to try these for laptops. Thanks Vladi
[External USB CD/DVD drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GStD.png)

Comment: Short answer: No. The USB is going into the drive not out of it.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer --> USB is going into the drive. What about the output of the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MMC MP3 SD USB Audio Player](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015OBJFMS) *might* work, though I've not tried it. You'd need a 12 V power supply and headphone (3.5 mm?) to RCA cable for the Bose line input.

The [Car Radio Car Kit FM Transmitter Modulator USB SD Slot Music Player](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011N2LVU6) *might also* be usable as an FM feed, though FM has a maximum bandwidth of ~15 kHz. You'd still need a 12 V supply.

[The question author also suggests a Blutooth adapter, but that might [limit audio quality](https://www.lifewire.com/what-to-know-about-bluetooth-3134591) without correct codecs.]

In either case, you'd likely get as good audio quality with a PC using the headphone output to the Bose line input.

Comment: thanks, your suggestions should work, so far I connected a bluetooth dongle receiver/transmitter to BOSE RCA inputs then I can play anything from smartphones, laptops CD ROM and so on !!

Comment: Great! How does it sound? Bluetooth uses compression (and FM bandwidth is limited, too). https://www.lifewire.com/what-to-know-about-bluetooth-3134591

Comment: BOSE sound systems always have a awesome reputation regarding to sound quality, when I stream from my laptop CD ROM to BOSE , for me, the sound output has very high quality besides that I can use an equalizer(from VLC) from my laptop to make thin adjustments to the sound. Short comment : It Sounds AWESOME, Thanks.